# How to randomly generate observations for a tibble while respecting existing columns types?

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

Assume I have an empty tibble `my_tbl` (0 rows) but whose column types are given. For example:

```r
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)

my_tbl <- tibble(
  x = integer(),
  y = character(),
  w = ymd(),
  z = list()
  )
```

How to randomly populate `my_tbl` with `n` rows (let's say `n=10` for the sake of demonstration)?

If possible I am looking for a simple `tidyverse` piece of code (but base R would be just fine too).

I understand that my requirements do not fully specify how to fill those rows but something that is not simply recycling a value for each column would already suffice. I'd like to have a simple way of randomly generating `tibbles` given known column types. The ultimate goal is to run tests on these generated `tibbles`.

Comment: What would a randomly generated `list()` be? You must have some pool of "reasonable" values from which you want to draw for each of those columns. It's not clear exactly what your definition of "random" is here for each of these columns.

Comment: @MrFlick: A list of a single object, of whatever base type would be okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function that calls `sample` to generate each column randomly:

```
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

get_random_tbl <- function(tbl, n){
  classes <- map_chr(tbl, class)
  map_dfc(
    classes,
    ~{
      switch(
        .x,
        integer = sample(1:100, n, replace = TRUE),
        character = sample(LETTERS, n, replace = TRUE),
        Date = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2019/01/01'), by = "day"), n, replace = TRUE),
        list = sample(c(list("x"), list(1)), n, replace = TRUE),
        stop()
      )
    }
  )
}


get_random_tbl(my_tbl, 3)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#      x y     w          z        
#  <int> <chr> <date>     <list>   
#1    18 V     2015-11-30 <dbl [1]>
#2    34 D     2004-05-26 <chr [1]>
#3    76 B     2007-03-16 <chr [1]>
```

Comment: Thanks for your example but I'd like some code that works for an arbitrary tibble with potentially more columns and different types. Your example is hardcoded to my example tibble.

Comment: See my edit, you can add your tibble as an argument and then use a `switch` statement to generate the correct data based on type. This should work on an arbitrary tibble given you define a random data generation function for each possible type in the `switch` statement.

Comment: Can you explain how the formula expression `~{...}` is working there?

Comment: That is a purrr shortcut for an anonymous function, it is equivalent to `function(...) {...}`